# Can't get the right syntax for the service monitoring SNMP in Nagios

Tags: snmp, nagios

I can't get this to work and I am curious... What I am doing wrong...:)

I a debian server with Nagios Core 4.4 on it, I want to add custom commands to have a better monitoring system and monitor more services.

I have imported the MIB file of my nutanix HCI en copied it into the nagios server (**/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NUTANIX.MIB.txt**)

When I run this on the nagios server, I get a correct output.

```
./check_snmp -P 3 -U nagios -L authPriv -a SHA [key] -x AES -X [key] IP -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.508.0
```

When I put this in my commands.cfg

```
define command{
          command_name check_snmp_clusterstatus
          command_line /usr/local/nagios/libexec/./check_snmp -P 3 -U nagios -L authPriv -a SHA -A [key] -x AES -X [key] IP -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.508.0
          }
```

And this in my host file

```
define host{
        use             generic-server
        host_name       hostname
        alias           hostname
        address         IP
    hostgroups  test-hosts
        }


define service{
        use                     CHECK_SNMP_V3
        host_name               Cluster
        service_description     ClusterIops
        flap_detection_enabled  1
        check_command           check_snmp!--protocol=3 -U nagios -L authPriv -a SHA -A [key] -x AES -X [key] -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.508.0
        }
```

It does not work, I can't get it to work. Does someone know the right syntax or what am I doing wrong here...

I have tried this guide, but for me it's not working.

The error keeps coming about the service which isn't configured correctly.

https://next.nutanix.com/how-it-works-22/monitoring-nutanix-with-nagios-4500

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you look into the nagios log and include the error(s) being thrown from Nagios?

Comment: “The error”? Why don’t you include it?

Comment: Which do you mean, from the /usr/local/nagios/var/ folder? It doesn't say anything. But when I run "journal -xe" it says there's a error in the service code. But what.... hehe :)

Comment: Try using the defined command name?  "command_name check_snmp_clusterstatus"  But what command are you using in your service definition?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the command you created from your 'service' definition.  It should look like this:

```
define service{
    use                     CHECK_SNMP_V3
    host_name               Cluster
    service_description     ClusterIops
    flap_detection_enabled  1
    check_command           check_snmp_clusterstatus!--protocol=3 -U nagios -L authPriv -a SHA -A [key] -x AES -X [key] -o 1.3.6.1.4.1.41263.508.0
    }
```